# How to show a form field ONLY if another is selected in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputColor">Collor</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="form.add.color" name="color" value="red">  red
      <input type="radio" ng-model="form.add.color" name="color" value="green">  green
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputProbleme">Problème</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProbleme" ng-model="form.add.probleme" name="probleme" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputDate">Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputDate" ng-model="form.add.date" name="date" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputService">Service</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputService" ng-model="form.add.service" name="service" placeholder="123...">
    </div>
  </div>            

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="inputVu">Vue</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="form.add.vu" name="vu" value="true">  True
      <input type="radio" ng-model="form.add.vuD" name="vu" value="false">  False
    </div>
  </div>
```

So what I want to do here is, when I select "red", the form will show "proleme" and "date" inputs to fill in, and when I select green it will show "service" and "vue". I know that we can do that using jquery or javascript, but how to do with Angularjs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple as hell. When red is selected, the value of `form.add.color` will be `'red'`. Whereas when green is selected, its value will be `'green'`.

So you just need to use the [`ngShow` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) on the divs you want to show/hide based on the selection:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="form.add.color == 'red'">
```

or

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="form.add.color == 'green'">
```